# How check the .spriteatlas sizes generated by Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, textures, texture-atlas

I'm using texture atlas for handling my images. I didn't created the atlas by myself however I let Xcode to do this for me:

[image]

My question is: How can I see this file or know its properties (I mean, sizes and weight)? What if and how can I know if the sizes exceed the maximum size of 4098 x 4098 pixel?