# What's really happens when I create a "New Sprite Image" inside my Xcode images.xcassets?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcasset, atlas

Days ago I asked for [How check the .spriteatlas sizes generated by Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33561727/how-check-the-spriteatlas-sizes-generated-by-xcode) but I got no answer so I decided to slightly change my question:

What happens when I choose this option here inside the `images.xcassets` section?

[image]

Does Xcode provide a full atlas manager and I just have to add single images inside this folder or should I put inside a whole atlas (created by my self with the .plist file attached)?

Comment: I assume this is a SpriteKit project?

Comment: Put a bunch of images in a folder named whatever with the extension of atlas.  Then drag and drop that folder directly onto your Xcode project.  You still have to know how to patch those tile files into a single platform map, though.

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes! Sorry I forgot to add this information